# Pyqt5 - can't run code after file dialog GUI has closed

Tags: python, pyqt5

My code is meant to manually select two .csv files (in separate folders) with Pyqt's openFileNameDialog, and then continue executing code not involving a GUI. I can get the file selection windows to run and select filenames, but then the code doesn't process any more. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QFileDialog

class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):        
        self.openFileNameDialog()
        self.openFileNameDialog2()

    def openFileNameDialog(self):
        print('Getting file 1 location')
        filepath, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open report 1", "", "csv (*.csv)")
        print('File 1 location: ',filepath)

    def openFileNameDialog2(self):
        print('Getting file 2 location')
        filepath2, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open report 2", "", "csv (*.csv)")
        print('File 2 location: ',filepath2)

    def closeEvent(self):
        super(QWidget,self).closeEvent()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

### The code doesn't run past this point
file1 = pd.read_csv(filepath, encoding='utf-8')
print(file1[0])

file2 = pd.read_csv(filepath2, encoding='utf-8')
print(file2[0])
```

Comment: that line of code will never be called, you must place that code inside the GUI when you have both files.

Comment: Two problems: (1) calling `sys.exit` will terminate the script before it gets to the code below it; (2) the `filepath` variables aren't global, so they cannot be accessed outside the open-dialog methods.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

for example:

```
# ...
def openFileNameDialog(self):
    print('Getting file 1 location')
    filepath, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open report 1", "", "csv (*.csv)")
    print('File 1 location: ',filepath)

    # read file1
    file1 = pd.read_csv(filepath, encoding='utf-8')
    print(file1[0])

def openFileNameDialog2(self):
    print('Getting file 2 location')
    filepath2, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open report 2", "", "csv (*.csv)")
    print('File 2 location: ',filepath2)

    # read file2
    file2 = pd.read_csv(filepath2, encoding='utf-8')
    print(file2[0])
# ...
```